# Does intensity of sound depend on temperature or humidity?

Tags: waves, acoustics, intensity

The intensity of sound $I$ can be written as $$ I = 2 \rho v (af \pi)^2$$
I googled and found that increase or decrease of temperature doesn't have any impact on sound intensity. But why is that? Surely, temperature has a role in sound velocity $v$, as we know,
$$v \propto \sqrt{T}$$.

So, shouldn't temperature play a role as well?

Also, we know the more is humidity, the less is the density of air. So, again, shouldn't humidity also play a role?

TIA

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The perceived or measured intensity depends on the source power and distance to the source. To first order, energy is conserved in sound transmission which means energy in (delivered by the source to the surrounding space) equals energy out (through a spherical surface centered on the source with radius = distance to source). sound velocity doesn't enter into the argument.

Comment: What about the formula then?

Answer (score 0):

In matter of principle both humidity and temperature are related to the speed of sound because a change in humidity leads to a change in the medium density as well as a change in temperature.

Raising the temperature correspond to a rarefied gas and thus the sound velocity decrease, while increasing the humidity decrease the density of the air (dry air weighs more than humid air).

In an ideal gas, the equation for the speed of sound
is $$v=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma R T}{M}}$$ where $\gamma$ is the adiabatic index, $R$ is the universal constant of an ideal gas and $T$ is the absolute temperature in Kelvin and $M$ is the molecular mass. In general, the more rigid (or less compressible) the medium, the faster the speed of sound
.

And about intensity:

The denser the medium, the more intense the wave. That makes sense. A dense medium packs more mass into any volume than a rarefied medium and kinetic energy goes with mass.

The faster the wave travels, the more quickly it transmits energy. This is where you have to remember that intensity doesn't so much measure the amount of energy transferred as it measures the rate at which this energy is transferred

Comment: And what impact does it have on intensity?

Comment: As you wrote above intensity depends linearly on density of the medium and speed of sound. So, fixing other quantities and looking at density variation: if the density increase the intensity would increase as well.

Comment: The denser the medium, the more intense the wave. That makes sense. A dense medium packs more mass into any volume than a rarefied medium and kinetic energy goes with mass.

The faster the wave travels, the more quickly it transmits energy. This is where you have to remember that intensity doesn't so much measure the amount of energy transferred as it measures the rate at which this energy is transferred